# jQuery UI Datepicker weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having a weird problem while working with a simple datepicker using jqueryUI. I simply want to show a two month calendar with LAST month and current month. I used this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#picker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showCurrentAtPos: 1,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function () {
            $('#out').html(this.value);
        }
    });
});

<div id="picker"></div>
<output id="out"></output>
```

It displays what I want but with an strange behavior as you can check here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xgvargas/UCbxf/

When you select a date it jumps to other month and, in some cases, the selected date is no longer visible, even if the date it returns is correct.

If you remove the line **showCurrentAtPos:1**, then this behavior stops but in this case I'll have current month and next one, this is not what I need.

Is this a bug or am I forgeting something?

By the way, I'm using the last version of jquery and jqueryUI. And only tested in Chrome so far.

Comment: showCurrentAtPos used only to display the current month at desired position. It is not for defining the behavior after the select is performed

Comment: No, I saw this before asking here, this fixes a problem when showing the datepicker, my problem occurs after the used selects a date.

Comment: may be you can to reset the datepicker based on the selected date

Comment: It's a strange behaviour...you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/huPSb/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a jQuery UI datepicker bug [**ticket**](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7288) it happens when the datepicker calculate and draw the months and doesn't use well the current month difference defined by `showCurrentAtPos`.

A possible solution is to add this block of code to the `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` file as reported in the ticket:

```
if (inst.drawMonth == showCurrentAtPos){

drawMonth = inst.drawMonth - showCurrentAtPos;

} else{

drawMonth = inst.drawMonth;

}
```

or to apply a patch in your `onSelect` function as you think:

```
onSelect: function (dateText, datePicker) {
    datePicker.drawMonth += $("#picker").datepicker("option", "showCurrentAtPos");
    $('#out').html(this.value);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huPSb/1/

Answer (score 2):

if you change select function with this code, everything will work fine

```
  onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
         inst.drawMonth +=1; 
        $('#out').html(this.value);
    }
```

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/4FFnp/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and patched the jquery-ui.js in basically two code lines in the datepicker subroutines _adjustDate() and _updateDatepicker():

```
--- jquery-ui.orig.js   2015-11-23 20:04:52.000000000 +0100
+++ jquery-ui.js    2015-11-23 17:56:37.987111191 +0100
@@ -8815,6 +8815,8 @@
        origyearshtml = inst.yearshtml = null;
        }, 0);
    }
+       // FIX BUG http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7288
+       inst.drawMonth += this._get(inst, "showCurrentAtPos");
},

// #6694 - don't focus the input if it's already focused
@@ -8940,9 +8942,14 @@
    if (this._isDisabledDatepicker(target[0])) {
        return;
    }
+       // FIX BUG http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7288
+       /*
        this._adjustInstDate(inst, offset +
        (period === "M" ? this._get(inst, "showCurrentAtPos") : 0), // undo positioning
        period);
+       */
+       this._adjustInstDate(inst, offset, period);
+
    this._updateDatepicker(inst);
},
```

The bug fix has been submitted upstream in http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9923#comment:4 , http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7580?cnum_edit=5#comment:5 , http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7580#comment:5 )