# jQuery ui calendar click error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using standart jQuery ui calendar inline with 2 month:

```
$('#datapicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showCurrentAtPos: 1
    });
```

Default stylesheet from jQuery UI, but in this way, when I click on date `(td > a)`, it changes the month. For the example if month is September and second is October and I click to select date, it changes month to previous August - September. Next and previous links, works just fine.

jsFiddle - [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/sbLnzob3/1/)

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Please add a working fiddle that reproduce the bug...

Comment: Do you need to use `showCurrentAtPos`?

Comment: jsFiddle is added.

Comment: Are you sure the `next` and `previous` links are working properly? The fiddle starts out displaying July/August, and after clicking `next`, November/December is displayed. Is this intentional?

Comment: This is because of `showCurrentAtPos` I correct it to 2. Click date bug (if it is bug) still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the behavior I described in my comment on your question is intentional, you can try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjh42/xtpec0tu/).

HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<br>
<label>Selected Date: </label>
<span id="out"></span>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showCurrentAtPos: 3,
        onSelect: function (dateText, datePicker) {
          datePicker.drawMonth += $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "showCurrentAtPos");
          $('#out').html(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

(reference: [jQuery UI Datepicker weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955134/jquery-ui-datepicker-weird-behavior))